# How to prevent Visual Studio 2008 from expanding excluded folders when opening solution?

Tags: visual-studio

We just migrated to Visual Studio 2008 from 2005.  Now whenever I open our project solution the solution explorer auto expands every directory that is excluded or contains an excluded file.

Comment: Did you copy over your options?

Tools->Import and Export Settings...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why it would expand every excluded item, but you can click the "Show All Files" icon at the top of solution explorer which will toggle whether or not it shows hidden/excluded items.